# Creating or saving model (.fbx or .stl) file in XNA

Tags: 3d, xna-4.0

I have drawn a 3-D Sphere in XNA with the help of vertices (without fbx file).

Now I want create a .fbx file or .stl file of this 3D sphere from XNA, is there any way to do this?

or how can I save this sphere to any format type file.

Answer (score 1):

When drawing the sphere perspective has no meaning, since the sphere looks like a circle from any angle. The most important part of drawing a sphere is showing its volume. You can do this by carefully examining the light, shades, the reflected light and highlights. To draw a good circle, you can first draw a square and then draw the circle inside it. Notice that the sphere's shade on the table has the shape of an ellipse.

While drawing, try to see the object as an image. Be bold with your lines and don't worry about making mistakes. You can always fix them later. Don't worry about the construction lines or smudges.

Comment: creating sphere is not my problem.I have fully designed 3-d sphere.Problem is I want to save or create a model( .fbx file or .stl file) from this 3d sphere that i have designed using vertices or math logics .

Comment: @uncle_scrooge just letting you know this user can't reply to your comment due to being suspended. (So don't waste time waiting for such a reply)